# Blazor - running a nightly process

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, daemon

I plan to have my server app running on Azure on 2+ servers each on 3 datacenters. I need to run a nightly process that closes all items that completed that day. Completion is datetime based, there is no user action that occurs that leads to a close.

So where/how should I run this process? It's composed of a number of Entity Framework queries and then will send out a set of emails. And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using Azure Durable Functions with Fan Out pattern.

- Provides a code-first approach where you can trigger a function on a schedule. This is more flexible if you need to run complex logic.
- In the fan out/fan in pattern, you execute multiple functions in parallel and then wait for all functions to finish. Often, some aggregation work is done on the results that are returned from the functions.

[image]

Comment: But where do I kick this off from? I have 6+ servers running, I don't want 6+ functions running. TIA

Comment: Azure Functions will not be running on any of your servers, Azure Functions is part of serverless architecture. You will be using a Timer Trigger to run the required function at a specific time.